# ag-grid hide rows with select all checkbox only works on filtered items

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid in my angular project. One of my columns uses checkboxes for filtering and has a search bar and a select all checkbox. When the select all box is unchecked when you searched for something, only the items that match the search term are deselected instead of everything.

[image: select all checkbox]

This question was already asked on github : https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1559.
Here, the answer was given to set the selectAllOnminiFilter to false. However, in the changelog of ag-grid, it says the selectAllOnMiniFilter property is removed : https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/ (key: AG-3383)

Is there a way to get this behavior without the selectAllOnminiFilter property?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get all nodes using

```
forEachNode((node, index))
```

and then uncheck the node.

You could do it using the following

```
gridApi.forEachNode(node => node.setSelected(false));
```

According to [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessing-data/), this will not ignore any sorted or filtered nodes.

> Iterates through each node (row) in the grid and calls the callback
>   for each node. This works similar to the 'forEach' method on a
>   Javascript array. This is called for every node, ignoring any
>   filtering or sorting applied within the grid. If using infinite row
>   model, then gets called for each page loaded in the page cache.

Comment: my problem is not really with selecting the rows but hiding all the rows when the select all checkbox is unchecked.